# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list

Tags: python

I have a program in python that takes a list and returns how many elements in the list that are evenly divisible by an integer x. For example, from the list `l = [1,3,3, 'hello']` and the integer `x = 3` I get the output `2`.

```
def my_div_calc(l,x):
    sum = 0
    for i in l:
        if type(i) == int or type(i) == float:
            i/x
            if i%x == 0:
                sum += 1
        else:
            sum += 0
    return sum
```

But if I have a list in my list, i.e if I have `l = [1,3,[3], 'hello']` instead. Then I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

I understand why I get this (because you can't divide a list with an `int`), but I don't know how I can fix it- I want the program to divide what is in the list just as usual so that it in this case also get the output `2`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure? I think the program runs well

Comment: I copied paste your code and didn't catch the error.

Comment: As others have said, your program runs well. What python interpreter and version are you using? Maybe the error comes from there.

Comment: I'm sure that the claimed `TypeError` came from a previous version of this program. The current program has a fix in checking for types.

Comment: Thank you all! I will review which version I have and update this if it is an old one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is one application for a recursive solution:

```py
def my_div_calc(l, x):
    sum = 0
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float):
            if i % x == 0:
                sum += 1
        elif isinstance(i, list):
            sum += my_div_calc(i, x)
    return sum


print(my_div_calc([1,3,[3], 'hello'], 3))
```

Output: `2`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a flat list from the list received by the method and after that work with it

```
def my_div_calc(l,x):
    sum = 0
    flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
    for i in flat_list:
        if type(i) == int or type(i) == float:
            i/x
            if i%x == 0:
                sum += 1
        else:
            sum += 0
    return sum
```

Comment: ```TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable```. This won't work if you have numbers, which is what OP question is based on

Comment: Have you tried this?